# How to put serial number list and database values in an multidimensional array together?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add serial number list and database values in a multidimensional array together to make list of tasks which are fetched from the database and printed using the array.

Here is my piece of code.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $query = mysqli_query($sqlconn, 'SELECT task FROM tasks');
    $task[] = array();
    while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $i++;
        array_push($task[0], $i);
        array_push($task[1], $a[0]);
    }
    echo '<br/>You are having <b style="color:red;">' . $i . '</b> tasks to do.<br/><br/>';
    foreach($task as $tasks)
    {
        echo $tasks[0] . '. ' . $tasks[1] . '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

I'm a beginner to programming and PHP.

I want to get the output like
1. This is task 1
2. This is task 2
3. This is task 3 and its not generating that from that array $task.

Comment: please better explanation....

Comment: I'm not able to print like.
1. Task 1
2. Task 2
3.(These are script sided serial list) Task 3(these are from DB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping the result to create the array
and than looping again to output it...
you can

> SIMPLIFY .... maybe like this ?

```
$i = 0; 
$query = mysqli_query($sqlconn, 'SELECT task FROM tasks');
$tot = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo '<br/>You are having <b style="color:red;">' . $tot . '</b> tasks to do.<br/><br/>'; 
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{   
     echo $i++ . '. ' . $a[0] . '<br/>';
}
```

If you **really need to store it in an array and than output** it:

```
$task = array();
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $task[] = array($i++, $a[0]);
}
foreach($task as $tasks)
{
    echo $tasks[0] . '. ' . $tasks[1] . '<br/>';
}
```

> little explaination

IN php you crate an array like this :

```
# this...
$array = array('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'bbbb');

# ... is the same as:
$array = array();
$array[] = 'aaaa';
$array[] = 'bbbb';
$array[] = 'cccc';

# ...is the same as:
$array = array();
$array[0] = 'aaaa';
$array[1] = 'bbbb';
$array[2] = 'cccc';

# Multi dimentional : just set each array entry as an array itself:

$array = array();
$array[0] = array('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc');
$array[1] = array(0=>'aaaa', 1=>'bbbb', 2=>'cccc');
$array[1][2] = array('dddd', 'eeee');
```

Please for more read the documentation : [PHP ARRAY](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, And can you explain me how it actually work? the second one with the array.

Comment: Thanks Federico, Can you explain it with how it worked with multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things quite a bit.

```
$query = mysqli_query($sqlconn, 'SELECT task FROM tasks');
$tasks = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $tasks[] = $row['task'];
}
echo 'Total tasks: '.sizeof($tasks);
foreach ( $tasks as $key => $value ) {
    echo 'Task #'.$key.': '.$value;
}
```

It isn't necessary to manually increment each key ($i) because PHP will do that for you.  Does each task have a primary key?  If so, consider using that as the array key because it will make searching the array much easier.

```
$query = mysqli_query($sqlconn, 'SELECT task_id, task FROM tasks');
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $tasks[$row['task_id']] = $row['task'];
}
// Get a single task
if ( isset($tasks[25]) ) {
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can you explain me your code a bit. I'm still a begginer and learning PHP, I didn't code in PHP since 7 or 8 months, So if you explain me code it would help me tho. I'm using the solution given by @Federico but it would be good If understand your code aswell :)